# Saving OSM map tiles in app project

Tags: android, osmdroid, offline-mode

Just wondering is it possible to add the saved map tiles from the mobile atlas to the project instead of sd card?

i want the map tiles to be available within the app i will be releasing. It is a free app on android market.

The map tiles are divided into 4 zip files, is it possible to keep and use them from the project file or do i need an online server to download them from.

Any help would be great

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One options is to use the assets folder to store files and then copy them to your private app data directory. Something like this should work. This copies a database, but you could adapt it to copy your zip files.

```
/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled. This is done by transfering
 * bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH.toString();
    // boolean success = DB_PATH.mkdirs();

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}
```